# Neo4j Web Application-Text Storage and Modeling

Tags: web-applications, neo4j, cypher, data-modeling

I am planning on using Neo4j for a project where we  store/encode sections of the Talmud (a jewish law code and a seminal text in Jewish life) and we are modeling these sections based on a typology so all of the sections we would choose would be the nodes of the graph (with various properties), and then their type would be a relationship so section x has type y along with section z and section r and so on.

One front end capability I would like is for the results of query to be exported to a pdf showing the text of resulting nodes from a query, is there a specific library that has this feature?

I have two specific 'back-end' questions related to this use case:

1. Can Neo4j handle nodes containing text strings (around 1000-5000 characters)? So for example if someone ran a query for all nodes  that had a certain relationship or certain property they could export the specific text like I mentioned above?
2. Each of our nodes would likely have 4 properties (page, chapter, book, and order of book (all books of the talmud are part of one of six specific larger collections called orders) and I want those properties to be query-able i.e. find all nodes with a specific property (specific page or chapter) and then the specific relationship is this set-up not optimal for neo4j and those properties should become separate nodes connected by a relationship like found_on or contained_in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. storing text strings of few 1000 bytes for a property does not cause any problems. However storing huge chunks of binary data as property values (think e.g. raw image data) you might be better off putting those into e.g. S3 and store instead the URLs to them as property values.
2. I suggest to make the structure as explicit as possible. The `orders` are linked to their books using `CONTAINS_BOOK` relationships, each page could be a node, being part of a chapter. Everything that is a thing on it's own should be a node on its own. Relationship types like `found_on` or `contained_in` make a lot of sense.